# Error when using both withDefaults and defineProps in <script setup> in Vite + Vue project

Tags: vue.js, webstorm

I am working on a project using Vite + Vue. However, I am getting the following error in the code below. After doing some research, I found out that using both `withDefaults` and `defineProps` in the `<script setup>` is not supported. When I run it in development mode, I can see that the prop handling is working. Can you help me with this issue?

I am developing in WebStorm, just to let you know.

```
<script setup lang="ts">
interface testInterface {
  name: string;
  much?: number;
}

const definesProp = withDefaults(defineProps<testInterface>(), {
  name: 'jarry',
});
</script>
```

The error:

```
Argument type DefineProps<testInterface, BooleanKey<testInterface>> is not assignable to parameter type DefineProps<Readonly<testInterface> & {}, keyof Readonly<testInterface> & {}>
```

Comment: I have the same problem, did you find a workaround?

Comment: I think this problem is exist with vue 3.3.x, but not with vue 3.2.x

Comment: workaround: use another web IDE like PHPStorm or Inteleij. Yes, I know this is not what you want xD, It is also not what I want, I rather wait..!

Comment: Just above https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#defineprops-defineemits It is explained that 3.3 has some changes in type calculations, I think it is due to that change that Webstorm has a difficult time with this.

Answer (score 3):

This is a WebStorm issue and since today, this error should be fixed since they implemented and fixed some volar issues.

I tried it and in my case, it is working normally.

[image: WebStorm 2023.1.3 update changelog]

Comment: Ouch! That's an error. I updated to 2023.1.3 but I still get this message.

Answer (score 1):

This is the IDE bug, tracked at [WEB-61241](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-61241/Vue-defineProps-together-with-withDefaults-results-in-type-matching-error); please follow it for updates

Comment: Your link 404's on me

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this is a webstorm issue, not the Vue itself, cause it only appears in WS.

All you can do is wait for jetbrains to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

the change vue server helped me
[image]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).