# After update of Vue 3 withDefaults throws a TypeScript error

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, webstorm

I'm trying to update version of Vue 3 (`3.2.x` -> `3.3.x`).

But for some reason I have an error when using `withDefaults`:

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
interface Props {
  readonly title: string;
}

// THIS WORKS
const props = defineProps<Props>(); 

// THIS DOESN'T WORK (guess because of withDefaults)
const props = withDefaults(defineProps<Props>(), { title: '' });
...
</script>
```

The error message is:

> Argument type `DefineProps<Props, BooleanKey<Props>>` is not assignable to parameter type `DefineProps<Readonly<Props> & {}, keyof Readonly<Props> & {}>`

I guess I'm doing this exactly how it's [described in docs](https://vuejs.org/guide/typescript/composition-api.html#typing-component-props), what's the problem here?

---

**Update**: Looks like this issue happens only for non-boolean fields:

```js
// THIS WORKS
withDefaults(defineProps<{readonly foo: boolean}>(), { foo: true });


// THIS DOESN'T WORK
withDefaults(defineProps<{readonly foo: string}>(), { foo: 'foo' });
```

Comment: I couldn't replicate your problem in a sandbox environment using vue 3.3.0. Can you provide more details about the code?

Here is a working example - https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/brave-cannon-jbnz8n?file=%2Fsrc%2Fcomponents%2FHelloWorld.vue%3A6%2C26

Comment: Maybe you need upgrade your typescript too

Comment: @Duannx I have upgraded the typescript still I get this error message.

Comment: How about the Volar extension? You should make sure vscode use the right typescript version

Comment: @Duannx vscode... I use webstorm. Maybe something in vue 3.3.x  that doesn't really supported by webstorm, and that's not the TS error

Comment: I think you should create a discussion in the Vue project. There you will get better advices

Comment: Similar kind of issue: https://stackoverflow.com/q/76313288/783119

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the IDE bug, tracked at [WEB-61241](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-61241/Vue-defineProps-together-with-withDefaults-results-in-type-matching-error); please follow it for updates

as a workaround, you can try downloading the [WebStorm 2023.2 EAP](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/nextversion/) and enabling Volar support in **Preferences | Languages & Frameworks | TypeScript | Vue**

Comment: The issue is closed. This is now the declared way to handle Vue typings, not a workaround any more.